# Spring MVC - cannot display Date/Time format in JSP from @DateTimeFormat

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Good morning.
I'm trying just to display in a jsp view a date/time value.

This value is saved in the DB with a simple CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
In the view, without formatting it i have it displayed in this way:

> **2015-12-03 11:43:13.0**

But, in the model I have annotated it in this way

```
@NotNull
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm")
    @Column(name = "date_time", nullable = false)
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return this.dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
```

So, when trying to render it in the view, i use:

```
<spring:eval expression="'${ill.MaxDate}'" />
```

In this way, the value should take care of the annotation pattern, right?

But I continue to display it as without formatting...

What I'm doing wrong?
PS: is it correct to format the date and time in the view process or I should format it in the controller before passing it to the model?

Thanks

Comment: You can use JSTL for it If I am not wrong.

Comment: You may add on you JSP the reference: <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

And use the formatting as: <fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" value="${ill.MaxDate}" />

Comment: Thanks, but it looks to me that this is a wolkaround or not? `spring:eval` should consider the @DateTimeFormat in the model, otherwise with fmt, the annotation in quite senseless, right?